# WCF REST Uri on Help page is not Correct

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, rest, wcf-rest

Been writing my first WCF Rest service and its going well... but i have a small issue, can anyone help?

When i goto my help page which on local pc is like so

```
  http://localhost/WcfRestService1/help
```

It displays the following, but the URI is wrong, notice the URI is blank or only asks for the parameter {id}

```
Uri     Method      Description
            GET     Service at http://localhost/WcfRestService1/
            POST    Service at http://localhost/WcfRestService1/
{id}        GET     Service at http://localhost/WcfRestService1/{ID}
            PUT     Service at http://localhost/WcfRestService1/{ID}
            DELETE  Service at http://localhost/WcfRestService1/{ID}
```

It really should be (see below for my methods)

```
  Uri

  Tasks  Get .... 
  Users/{id}    Get ....
```

Here are my methods so surley the URI should show the correct URI, see my attribute UriTemplate

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Tasks")]
    public List<SampleItem> GetCollection()
    {
        // TODO: Replace the current implementation to return a collection of SampleItem instances
        return new List<SampleItem>() { new SampleItem() { Id = 1, StringValue = "Hello" } };
    }

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Users/{id}")]
    public SampleItem Get(string id)
    {
        // TODO: Return the instance of SampleItem with the given id
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        return new SampleItem() {Id = 1, StringValue = "Hello"};
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you browsing the correct service class? you said this is your first WCF rest project, is it possible that you have created another service class - other than WcfRestService1.